# How can I get rid of an unexpected newline at the of a code?

Tags: python, string, newline

I'm trying to transform each word from a txt file so that the carriage return is removed, and then have the words printed out. However, there's an extra newline at the end when I run the code. I checked for any extra spaces in the code, but I'm not sure how to remove it.

This is what I typed in:

```
f = open("/home/pride_and_prejudice.txt").read()
for word in f.split("\n"):
     word_new = word.rstrip("\n")
     print(word_new)
```

This should give me:

```
It
is
a
truth
universally
acknowledged
that
a
single
man
in
possession
of
a
good
fortune
must
be
in
want
of
a
wife
However
little
known
the
feelings
or
views
of
such
a
man
may
be
on
his
first
entering
a
neighbourhood
this
truth
is
so
well
fixed
in
the
minds
of
the
surrounding
families
that
he
is
considered
as
the
rightful
property
of
some
one
or
other
of
their
daughters
```

Comment: What does the original file look like?

Comment: What do you currently get?

Comment: If you split on `\n` there won't be any `\n` left to remove. To get individual words, you'd need to split on spaces.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "However, there's an extra newline at the end when I run the code" - no; there's an extra **empty string** at the end, because the *file contents* have a newline at the end and you make the list by splitting on newlines. The elements of the list **already don't** end with newlines because of the split, so `word_new = word.rstrip("\n")` **accomplishes nothing**. You see an extra newline at the end **from the `print` call**. Please see the linked duplicate for working approaches to the problem.

Comment: Please see the linked duplicate for working approaches to the problem - this is assuming that the file already has one word on each line. If you are trying to split up words from a multi-line file, simply call `.split()` instead of `.split('\n')` - if that is the issue I can link a different duplicate for that.